# How can I select points in SQL Server 2012 based on geography if they are text fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, nvarchar, geographic-distance

Okay I'm kind of stuck with this database, and I'm trying to make a "nearby" page for it.

What I have (unfortunately) is a `lat` and a `lon` column that are `nvarchar`. I can't convert them because they're needed elsewhere as text.

I would like to take the map point center, and put in some dots of places within a mile or so.

Can I somehow join these 2 text fields into one coordinates column to compare `STDistance`?

To do something like this..

```
SELECT * 
FROM goelocs 
WHERE coords.STDistance(geography::Point(54.1020, -115.12338, 4326)) <=(1609.344)
```

Or can you recommend a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do the values in NVARCHAR form look like? just `'54.1020' as lat` ?

Comment: yes exactly... one lat field one lat field. only numbers in them, but they are set as text ie. '54.1020'  and '-115.12338'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `NVarchar` columns are only the numeric value, like:

- lat: '54.103'
- lon: '-115.1'

SQL Server will handle implicitly converting them to a `float`. The following query will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM geolocs geo
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(geo.lat) = 1
    AND ISNUMERIC(geo.lon) = 1
    AND geography::Point(geo.lat, geo.lon, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(54.1020, -115.12338, 4326)) <= (1609.344)
```

Comment: I went with this.. It was obvious, but not to me lol. THANKS! @arserbin3



SELECT * FROM stops
WHERE geography::Point(stop_lat, stop_lon, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(51.013117,-114.0741555, 4326)) <= (500.0)